# ¿Cómo rellenar ComboBox con un la descripcion de objetos dentro de un ArrayList?

Tags: java

Tengo un `ArrayList` de objetos, los cuales los voy agregando de a uno a medida que necesito dar de alta (`Insumos`). Estos objetos tienen una descripción (nombre).

Necesito llenar un `ComboBox` con las descripciones de dichos objetos dentro del `ArrayList`.

Mi código es:

```
ComboBox<String> combito new = ComboBox<String>();
DefaultComboBoxModel modelito = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
combito.setModel(modelito);
```

Y aca viene la duda. ¿Debo recorrer todo el `Array` de objetos y utilizar mi metodo `toString()`  para rellenar el combo?

```
for i to (final array) 
    modelito.add(toString(ArrayList[i]))
```

¿Es así?

Comment: Puedes mostrar como creas el ArrayList  de objetos y la clase de tu objeto para detallar más tu pregunta!, saludos.

Comment: Hola, @Lenz si alguna de las respuestas puestas más abajo fue de especial utilidad, podrías *aceptarla* y/o votar positivamente.

Answer (score 4):

Simplemente realizas una iteración sobre tu Array de Objetos

```
for(Objeto objeto : ArrayObjetos) {
    combito.addItem(objeto.toString());
}
```

Pero me parece que lo que deseas es extraer alguna propiedad para agregarla al `ComboBox` y no agregar el objeto como `String`, por ejemplo si tu objeto tuviera un campo nombre, y tiene un método `getNombre()`, el cual obtiene el valor como `String`, ya no necesitarias hacer uso de `toString()` :

```
for(Objeto objeto : ArrayObjetos) {
    combito.addItem(objeto.getNombre());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente, debes alimentar el combo con cada elemento de tu `ArrayList`.

Yo lo haría así:

```
ComboBox<String> combito = new ComboBox<>(); // No es necesario volver a
                                             // especificar el tipo del combo... 
                                             // para eso sirve el <>
ArrayList<MiClase> al = miArrayList; // Asumo que este ArrayList guarda
                                     // objetos de clase MiClase.
for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
    combito.addItem(al.get(i).toString();
}
```

Otra forma:

```
for(MiClase elemento : al) {
    combito.addItem(elemento.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo mejor es refinir el método toString() de la clase Insumo:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return nombre;
}
```

Al combo lo declarás de manera que acepte objetos Insumo:

```
ComboBox<Insumo> combito new = ComboBox<Insumo>();
```

Y luego le agregás todos los objetos Insumo de tu colección al Combo:

```
for(Insumo ins : insumos) {
combito.addItem(ins);
}
```

Ésto permite que luego cuando recuperes el objeto desde el Combo sea el objeto completo y no una String.

Comment: Muchas gracias a Todos por sus respuestas!!! De verdad!! 

Afirmativamente mi clase Insumo tiene un método toString. y el ComboBox debo rellenarlo con un atributo dentro de un objeto de tipo Insumo. Creo que esta respuesta es la que más se acerca! intentare esta tarde al llegar a casa! Muchas gracias a todos!

Answer (score 1):

tienes tu combobox

```
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> miCombo
```

creas un DefaultComboBoxModel

```
DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
```

llenas el modelo

```
for(miObject obj:miArray){
        model.addElement(obj.getDescripcion());
```

}

seteas el modelo a tu combo

```
 miCombo.setModel(model);
```