# se puede llenar un combobox

Tags: vba

Hola mi inquietud es si se puede llenar un combobox directamente desde un recordset sin tener que repasar item por item algo asi como:

me.combobox1.rowsource (el nombre del recordset)
y que muestre los resultados. Gracias

Comment: Usa un for each, mira esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/9034/128207

Answer (score 0):

Si, crea tu consulta SQL, datos de conexión a la bbdd, etc. Luego declara un array (Dim arrData as variant) y mete en ese array todos lo que obtengas del recordset:

```
arrData = rs.GetRows
```

Ese array tendrás que transponerlo así:

```
Me.combobox1.list = application.transpose(arrData)
```

Aunque te recomiendo que para transponer matrices utilices esta función:

```
Function TransponerMatriz(arrData)

    Dim TempArray()
    ReDim TempArray(UBound(arrData, 2) + 1, UBound(arrData, 1) + 1) ' Note: VBScript is zero-based

    For i = 0 To UBound(arrData, 2)
    For j = 0 To UBound(arrData, 1)
        TempArray(i, j) = arrData(j, i)
    Next
    Next

    TransponerMatriz = TempArray

End Function
```

Con lo que quedaría así:

```
Me.combobox1.list = TransponerMatriz(arrData)
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con cualquiera de estas tres formas:

```
me.combobox1.rowsource = "Nombre_Consulta"

me.combobox1.rowsource = "Nombre_Tabla"

me.combobox1.rowsource = "SELECT Campo1, Campo2 [, etc.] FROM Tabla;"
```